# Proof Verification of Coset Multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Please verify my following proof:

**Theorem:** Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, then the left coset multiplication is well defined by the equation: $(aH)(bH)=(ab)H$ iff $H$ is a normal subgroup.

**Proof:**
$\boxed{\rightarrow}$  $(aH)(bH)=(ab)H$ as coset multiplication is well defined. *Then assigning $ah_1$ and $bh_2$ as representatives to $aH$ and $bH$ respectively we have (Italic is added for edditing as per comment suggestion):*  $$(aH)(bH) \rightarrow (ah_1)(bh_2) = (ab)h_3  \rightarrow h_1bh_2 = bh_3 \rightarrow h_1b=bh_3h_2^{-1} \rightarrow h_1b=bh_4$$

So all elements of $bH$ can be written in the form $Hb$, so $Hb=bH$, so $H$ is normal.

$\boxed{\leftarrow}$ $H$ is normal, so $aH=Ha$, need to show that $(aH)(bH)=(ab)H$. *Then assigning $ah_1$ and $bh_2$ as representatives to $aH$ and $bH$ respectively we have (Italic is added for edditing as per comment suggestion):*
$$(aH)(bH) \rightarrow (ah_1)(bh_2) = a(h_1b)h_2 = a(bh_3)h_2 = ab(h_3h_2) \rightarrow (ab)H$$ closure as $h_2$ and$h_3$ are arbitrary elements of the subgroup $H$.

QED.

I know that double inclusion is standard for proving set equality, but if I can show that all elements of set A can be written as all elements in set B, does that suffice to show $A=B$

Explicitly, I  showed that all elements in $aH$ can be expressed as elements of $Ha$. Does that suffice to show $aH=Ha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is good. And yes, showing $aH \subseteq Ha$ is not enough, but usually there is some sort of symmetry: your argument works the other way round perfectly.

---

I do think the proofs can be streamlined a little. Firstly, note

> $H$ is normal iff for all $a \in G$, $aHa^{-1} \subseteq H$.

This is an equivalent definition: it implies $aHa^{-1} \subseteq H$ and $a^{-1}Ha \subseteq H$. So $aH \subseteq Ha$ and $Ha \subseteq aH$ giving $aH=Ha$. The only advantage of this is we do not have to check equality.

*Proofs:*

> $(\Rightarrow)$ We have $(aH)(a^{-1}H) = H \Rightarrow (aHa^{-1})H = H \Rightarrow aHa^{-1} \subseteq H$.
>
> $(\Leftarrow)$ As $H$ is normal, $Hb=bH$, so $(aH)(bH) = a(Hb)H=a(bH)H=abH$, using $HH=H$.

The fact that I can manipulate the way I did in second line follows from associativity of group elements. For example, $(ah_1)(bh_2)= a(h_1b)h_2$.

---

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: Fantastic! You've also made me understand Fraleigh's proof with your explanation! AND you've supplied me with a more elegant and simpler proof AND you've shown me an equivalence I wasn't aware of. May I ask one tiny practical question though, to write the proof the way I did, I should prove that there is symmetry in the case I am proving. So should I say  something like "the right cosets and left cosets are of the same order as $H$ (symmetry?)" and/or "there are an equal amount of left cosets partition $G$, as there right cosets (symmetry?)"

Comment: What I meant in "symmetry" is more in the ideas of proof. For example, you have shown in $(\Leftarrow)$ of proof that  $aH bH \subseteq abH$. Now to show the other inclusion, pick $ab h_1 \in abH$, we have $abh_1= (ah_2)(be)\in aH bH $ from normality ($bh_1=h_2b$, where $h_1, h_2 \in H$). The general gist is the same for the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct.
Mybe you can give some little explanations in the direction $\longrightarrow,$ but
in general is o.k.

Comment: Is that better? @sti9111

Comment: Yes!! that´s better.